# How to stream mic input with little to no delay(over lan)

Tags: sound, streaming, icecast

Seems the default answer is icecast + darkice but many people mention a delay of anywhere from 1-5 seconds. Is this due to hardware limitations?

Answer (score 0):

Icecast is not the answer. It is not designed for very low latency. You can trim the delays down to below 1 second, but it's not consistent across multiple clients. So if you have more than one player connected they will start drifting apart. For use cases like you imply them a constant (sometimes even adjustable) sub 100ms latency is key.

An approach more likely to succeed is VoIP software or network transparent audio servers like Jack or PulseAudio.

Comment: thanks for the advice, I forgot to mention I need to access the stream in a web browser. Knowing that which would you recommend voip, pulse or jack? I think there are browser based SIP clients.

Comment: Then you should first look into WebRTC I guess. There might be SIP clients too, not sure. I don't have much experience with those.